# CakePHP Error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

I am getting the syntax error commented code.
Can some have idea, why this error comes

Error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
redmine/app/View/Welcome/index.ctp Line: 4

```
<h2><?php $this->Candy->html_title(__('Home'))  ?></h2>

<div class="splitcontentleft">
<!-- <%= textilizable Setting.welcome_text %> -->
<?php echo $this->Candy->textilizable($Settings->welcome_text) ?>
<?php if (!empty($news)): ?>
<div class="box">
<h3><?php echo __('Latest news')?></h3>
    <?php echo $this->element('news',array('news' => $news)) ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View all news'), array('controller' =>    
'news')) ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

**Also it works fine in localhost , It seems this is a .htaccess file issue?**

Thanks in advance...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `asp_tags` on in `php.ini` that's why you are getting this error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
```

you can disable `asp_tags` in your `.htaccess` like

```
php_flag asp_tags off
```

if you want to disable it for just a single file you can use this

```
<files file-with-asp-syntax.php>php_flag asp_tags off</files>
```

you can use this one also `ini_set('asp_tags', 0)`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have missing echo in your title. Use it like this:

```
<h2><?php echo $this->Candy->html_title(__('Home')); ?></h2>
```

Comment: Ok can you take a backup of this file and temporarily delete that line and above `<h2>` line?

Comment: @NarendraSinghRajpoot The code inside the HTML comment is not valid PHP code.

Comment: sorry actually i am newly on cakePHP
if this code is not valid then how it works in localhost?

Comment: As I suggested earlier, can you take a backup of this file and temporarily delete that commented line and above `<h2>` line?

Answer (score 0):

If you have asp_tags enabled php script will be processed no matter the fact that is commented in html. Just strip it off <%= and %> and it should work.

If such script would echo anythin it would be commented by html but still processed by PHP.